# Cast FileInfo into FileSystemInfo

Tags: vb.net

I am working on modifying file copy program that used to only copy a directory to another directory. Now I want to pass both directories and files in a list for the copy to run.

```
    For Each _fromPath In CopyList
        Dim FSinfo As FileSystemInfo()
        If Directory.Exists(_fromPath) Then
            Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(_fromPath)
            FSinfo = dir.GetFileSystemInfos
        ElseIf File.Exists(_fromPath) Then
            Dim file As New FileInfo(_fromPath)
            FSinfo = file
        End If

        CountFiles(FSinfo)

    Next

    Private Function CountFiles(ByVal FSInfo As FileSystemInfo()) As Boolean
```

This code works fine for directories. In order to pass paths to the CountFiles, they must be in FileSystemInfo. Is there anyway to get FileInfo casted as a FileSystemInfo.

I tried `CType(file, FileSystemInfo)` but it said `Value of type 'System.IO.FileInfo' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of System.IO.FileSystemInfo'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you are trying to convert an object (`FileInfo`) to an ARRAY of objects (`FileSystemInfo()`) which is what the error message is trying to tell you.  You could write an overloaded function to handle some of that:

```
' my Count functions return numeric values:
Private Function CountFiles(FSInfo As FileSystemInfo()) As Integer

Private Function CountFiles(FInfo As FileInfo) As Integer
```

Internal to them, the FileSystemInfo might call the other in a loop to avoid duplicate code, or maybe they both call a common procedure depending on how it is written.